# Many to many joined tables syntax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true

  has_many :items_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :items_categories

  has_many :item_orders
  has_many :orders, through: :item_orders

  def quantity

  end
end
```

My question is why we need the lines:

```
has_many :items_categories
```

and

```
has_many :items_oders
```

They seem redundant. Why do we need them?

To clarify, items and categories are a many-to-many relationship.
Items and orders are a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

`items_categories` and `item_orders` are fully-fledged associations with Item.  The Item class needs to know about them in order to "look through" them to find the categories and orders.

They are not redundant - why would you think that they were?  Often you will end up creating and deleting the join records, eg via an items_categories_controller or  item_orders_controller, in order to associate/unassociate existing items with existing order/categories.

Comment: What the OP means is that `has_many :orders, through: :item_orders` seems enough to determinate that the Item `has_many :item_orders`. Your answer doesn't really provide any explanation on why it is necessary

Comment: `through: :item_categories` doesn't actually define the "item-item_categories" association, it just refers to it.  Granted, rails *could* have been written differently so that it did both things at once, but it wasn't, and i'm not sure this would be a good idea.

Comment: I felt they were redundant because the line with through: says that it goes through those joined tables

Comment: Sometimes Ben Kenobi is wrong - you shouldn't always trust your feelings.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why isn't it a good idea? When would you write: has_many :categories, through: :items_categories without it sufficiently implying has_many :items_categories?